# Grouping of CFG grammar rules sentencewise

Tags: tree, parse-tree

Below specified rules are generated for each sentence. We have to group them for each sentence. The input is in file. Output also should be in file

```
sentenceid=2

NP--->N_NNP
NP--->N_NN_S_NU
NP--->N_NNP
NP--->N_NNP
NP--->N_NN_O_NU
VGF--->V_VM_VF

sentenceid=3

NP--->N_NN
VGNF--->V_VM_VNF
JJP--->JJ
NP--->N_NN_S_NU
NP--->N_NN
VGF--->V_VM_VF

sentenceid=4

NP--->N_NNP
NP--->N_NN_S_NU
NP--->N_NNP_O_M
VGF--->V_VM_VF
```

The above section containing input ,that is actually grammar for each sentence. I want to group adjacent rules sentence wise. Output should be like below.

```
sentenceid=2

NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
VGF--->V_VM_VF

sentenceid=3

NP--->N_NN
VGNF--->V_VM_VNF
JJP--->JJ
NP--->N_NN_S_NU N_NN
VGF--->V_VM_VF

senetnceid=4

NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP_O_M
VGF--->V_VM_VF
```

How can I implement this? I need almost 1000 sentences rules for probability calculation. This is the CFG grammar for each sentence, I want to group adjacent rules sentence-wise.

Comment: output of sentenceid=3 is not right, i think could you please check that

Comment: its correct..only adjacent NP's should be grouped..

Comment: ah sure, please the answer below.

Comment: Could you confirm one thing, all those sentence are in one file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: considering sentence are in different files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
marker = '--->'

def parse_it(sen):
    total_dic = dict()
    marker_memory = ''
    with open(sen, 'r') as fh:
        mem = None
        lo = list()
        for line in fh.readlines():
            if line.strip():
                match = re.search('(sentenceid=\d+)', line)
                if match:
                    if mem and lo:
                        total_dic[marker_memory].append(lo)
                    marker_memory = match.group(0)
                    total_dic[marker_memory] = []
                else:
                    k,v = line.strip().split(marker)
                    k,v = [ x.strip() for x in [k,v]]
                    if not mem or mem == k:
                        lo.append((k,v))
                        mem = k
                    else:
                        total_dic[marker_memory].append(lo)
                        lo = [(k,v)]
                        mem = k
        #total_dic[marker_memory].append(lo)
    return total_dic

dic = parse_it('sentence')
for kin,lol in dic.iteritems():
    print
    print kin
    for i in lol:
        k,v = zip(*i)
        print '%s%s %s' % (k[0],marker,' '.join(v))
```

Output:

```
sentenceid=3
VGF---> V_VM_VF
NP---> N_NN
VGNF---> V_VM_VNF
JJP---> JJ
NP---> N_NN_S_NU N_NN
VGF---> V_VM_VF

sentenceid=2
NP---> N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
VGF---> V_VM_VF

sentenceid=4
VGF---> V_VM_VF
NP---> N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP_O_M
```

Comment: @yopy...i am giving only 3 sentences here,i have almost 1000 sentences,what i have to modify..and another thing,here output came 3 times(no of sentence)

Comment: So, my question all those sentence are in the same file ? if yes then i ll change the snippet to work.

Comment: alright. let me change the snippet, considering it has unique sentence id

Comment: please try that now, i put all your sentence in one file called sentence and run that.

Comment: so you mean counting the number of repeated entry from one file to another file ?

Comment: yes check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519637/to-find-count-of-each-line-in-another-file

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file /home/kannan/suffixlist.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details   I got this error

Comment: hi ,re.match('NP',unidata).this is the actual format of regular expression..can we give a variable for re.match()??????

Comment: hi can u plz tell me [['\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x80\xe0\xb4\xa4', '\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x86']]..how can i convert this to language form

Comment: is that related to this question else please post in different question, otherwise no one will see your update.