# to find count of each line in another file

Tags: count, probability, rules

```
How can i get now of times a particular line of one file present in another file
```

I have two files rule.txt and full.txt.I want to check count of each line in rule.txt in full.txt.please help me
       In file rule.txt contain

```
    NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
    VGF--->V_VM_VF

    The another file full.txt contains 1000 of such type of rules. i want to calculate count of each rule in the rule.txt and I want to get output as line with count.that count is needed for the calculation of probability of each rule.rule.txt contain cfg rules of each sentence

    fc= codecs.open('full.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
    with open('rule.txt', 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
          if(line in fc.readlines()):
                print line
                count=count+1
    print count

    I have this code .but this is not working..plz help me.I need to calculate the probabilty of each  rule in the rule.txt by checking in full.txt.for probability calculation ,i need count of each rule individually.Can you please help me to count the no of times a rule present in full.txt
```

Comment: Ok, so I am considering `NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU` as one line ?

Comment: Ok ok.that line is 10 times present in full.txt

Comment: how can i draw tree in python..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your file is not super huge, and you ve enough memory:

Here is the file1 :

```
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
VGF--->V_VM_VF
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
```

Here is the file2 :

```
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
VGF--->V_VM_VF
VGF--->V_VM_VF
VGF--->V_VM_VF
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF
VGF--->V_VM_VF
VGF--->V_VM_VF
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
VGF--->V_VM_VF
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
VGF--->V_VM_VF
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU
```

Here is the code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python

  import pprint

  lines1 = set()
  with open('txt1', 'r') as f1:
      lines1 = set([x.strip() for x in f1.readlines()])

  line_dict = dict()
  with open('txt2', 'r') as f2:
      for line in f2.readlines():
          line = line.strip()
          line_dict.setdefault(line, 0)
          line_dict[line] = line_dict.get(line, 0) + 1

  for line in lines1:
      print '%s : %d' % (line, line_dict.get(line, 0))
```

Output:

```
VGF--->V_VM_VF : 7
VGF--->V_VM_VF KLF NFG_JP : 6
KGF--->V_VM_VF P_NSF SSF : 4
NP--->N_NNP N_NN_S_NU N_NNP N_NNP N_NN_O_NU : 8
```

Comment: How can i draw tree in python to represent above rules

Comment: not much sure about that, could you post another question, so everyone will see.

Comment: Ok i ll tag python now.

Comment: you mean number of lines in file ?

Comment: to count the duplicacy, you need to maintain a dictionary or set, to do that.

Comment: i don't want to count duplicate..i only want to count distinct lines in a file.

Comment: [['\xe0\xb4\xb8\xe0\xb5\x80\xe0\xb4\xa4', '\xe0\xb4\xaf\xe0\xb5\x86']]  how can i convert this output to any language